# Detecting if a Record in Airtable has been modified

Tags: api, go, last-modified, airtable

I am trying to stream data from an Airtable base to a local file.

I am working in go and using this airtable package

I want to be able to detect whether a record has been modified, without having to use the original data and comparing it to the current data in the base.

Fetching a record returns its ID, data and Created time. But nothing about whether it has been modified or not.

A solution I explored was to add the “Last modified time” field to all records, which would solve all my problems. But there is no way of doing that through API and has to be done manually. Not a great user experience!

I also am aware there is a webhook but am not keen to go down that route.

Is there any way I can get the “Last modified time” or any information that a change has been made and can narrow it down by the record?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

- Trigger an AirTable Automation based on a **record field value changing**.
- Trigger an AirTable Automation based on a **record entering a view**.
- Use webhooks to detect **when a record has changed**.

It sounds like, if you want to avoid webhooks, one of the first two will be your best bet, and if want to know every time that a `lastModifiedTime` field has changed, then the first would be the best. You could do a view based record update, but then you would need to clear your view filtereing field or store it in a different field and compare agains your `lastModifiedTime` field.

In AirTable, go to "Automations" and create (or edit) an automation. For the trigger type, select "When record updated". You can then specify the table, a specific view (optional), and exactly which fields you would like to watch for changes. You can then write a small javascript script inside the AirTable automation, or use it to call out to an external service. You can include specific field values from the updated reocrd, as well as the updated record ID.

You can read more about this automation trigger here

https://support.airtable.com/docs/when-record-is-updated-trigger

If you want more granularity in what kind of change triggered the change (API, manual upload, etc.), or previous values, you will need to use the webhooks API as it can provide all of this information. You can find more information about that here

https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/webhooks-overview